# Pig Store the file with custom row/record delimiter

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I Have a file with a ctrlB as a record delimiter. I was able to read the file in pig by over-writing LoaderInputFormat class and getInputFormat() method in pig storage. But I was not able to store the file with ctrlB as a record delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Read **ctrl+b** delimited record

```
SET textinputformat.record.delimiter '\n'
x= LOAD 'xyz' USING PigStorage('\u0002');
```

Write **ctrl+b** delimited record-

```
store x into 'y' using PigStorage('\u0002');
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, Thanks for the answer. The Solution you have give reads and stores CtrlB as a field delimiter,but I want read and write CtrlB as a line/record delimiter.  I have a over written LoaderInputFormat class and was able read the files with CtrlB as a line/record delimiter, but I was not able to store/write  a file with  CtrlB as a line/record delimiter

Comment: So basically I want textoutputformat to have record delimiter as '\u0002'

Comment: use for ctr+b delimiter: SET textinputformat.record.delimiter '\u0002'

Comment: Yes this is to read the file with ctrlB as record delimiter.   I want to store the file with ctrlB.

Comment: KC, I don't think so you have to write anything custom to have this functionality. You just need to pass '\u0002' as a delimiter in PigStorage during LOAD and STORE. PigStorage will take care of it.