# Setting textinputformat.record.delimiter in Hive to ^A of (\u0001)

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

My data contains control character(^A) as my record delimiter. Thus I want to set textinputformat.record.delimiter to ^A from Hive CLI so that TextInputFormat use this while reading data to segregate records. I tried the following in Hive CLI:

```
set textinputformat.record.delimiter=\u0001;
set textinputformat.record.delimiter=\\u0001;
set textinputformat.record.delimiter='\u0001';
set textinputformat.record.delimiter='\\u0001';
set textinputformat.record.delimiter=U+0001;
```

but nothing worked. Hive CLI interpret this as String literals. Please suggest something.

Comment: Hive cli is deprecated, by the way

Comment: Consider it to be beeline instesd of Hive CLI. The behaviour is the same.

Comment: This seems to answer using Pig with `^B` delimiter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38776692/pig-store-the-file-with-custom-row-record-delimiter

Comment: While creating table, defining record separator only supports '\n' (LINES TERMINATED BY). Please attach a link of the Hive tutorial you mentioned about.

Comment: I tried octal as well, but of no result. I tried textinputformat.record.delimiter=\001 and textinputformat.record.delimiter=\\001

Comment: Ah, my bad. I meant _"field separator"_ and that's off topic Honestly, with that kind of exotic files, I would simply run them through `tr` in a Linux shell to replace the Ascii-1 char with a standard EOL -- AFAIK Hive supports `LF` , `CR`, or `CR-LF` out of the box.